# It's $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ an $Z_n$-injective module?

Tags: homological-algebra, injective-module

It's $\mathbb{Q}/ \mathbb{Z}$ an $Z_n$-injective module, where $n\in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Rings are not principle: they are principal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't endow $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ with the structure of a module over $\mathbb{Z}_n$ exactly because it is divisible.

Since $n1_{\mathbb{Z}_n}=0$, we must have $nM=0$, for every module over $\mathbb{Z}_n$. Of course, for every divisible abelian group $G$ we have $nG=G$, by definition.

The fact that $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ is divisible is obvious, because $\mathbb{Q}$ is divisible.

---

The ring $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is self-injective, which you can prove with the help of Baer’s criterion. The ideals of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ have the form $m\mathbb{Z}_n$ for $m\mid n$. Suppose you have a homomorphism $f\colon m\mathbb{Z}_n\to\mathbb{Z}_n$; set $x=f(m)$. Then, for $q=n/m$,
$$
qx=qf(m)=f(qm)=f(0)=0
$$
so actually the image of $f$ is contained in $m\mathbb{Z}_n$. Now you can end.

Comment: Thank you! I try to find an injective resolution of $Z_n$ as $Z_n$ - module.

Comment: @rafa The ring $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is self-injective.

Comment: Why?  It's $\mathbb {Z}_n$ a divisible module? If I choose $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $x\in \mathbb{Z}_n$ then $n\cdot x=0$ always.  I have the same problem for $\mathbb{Z}_n$ as $\mathbb {Z}_{n^2}$-module.

Comment: @rafa Injective doesn't mean divisible.

Comment: Then I have to show that  $Ext^1_{\mathbb{Z}_n}  (\mathbb{Z}_n/I, Z_n)=0$ for all $I$ ideal of $\mathbb{Z}_n$. It is a easier way to prove the assertion?

Comment: Thank you very much but   I am not familiar with Baer's Criterion.  There exists another proof?